# Delete the first characters before parse an XML (SAX)

Tags: file-io, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser, xmlreader

I have who xml files apparently identical named wrong.xml and good.xml.

The code is the follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <tag>
    </tag>
```

The problem is that the XMLReader class (org.xml.sax.XMLReader) detects the follow error when parse the wrong.xml.

```
    Content is not allowed in prolog
```

The reason is that exist an hidden characters before prolog.

I only got to see these characters using a basic java file reader and I can see that the first and second characters are -1 and -2.

```
    '-1''-2'<?xml version>......
```

Notepad, Ultraedit32, Wordpad, Notepad++, etc. neither can see them.

My real problem is that I need read the xml from an FTP automatically, then I need any way for delete these characters before parse with xmlReader without parse all document because some documents are very big.

How delete the first char of a file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove those characters before the parser sees them, but you don't need to read the whole file and write it back out again with those characters removed.

A sax parser can read from an [`InputSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) based on a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html).  There are many implementations of this `Reader` interface for reading from a file, url or other data source, but you can also wrap whatever your primary `Reader` is in a [`FilterReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) extension that you code to perform changes needed to the data before it goes on.

It isn't difficult to code an extension of `FilterReader` that drops the first two characters but passes on everything else, and that will do just what you need.  If the need to drop those characters isn't known until runtime, but can be detected then in a sensible way, this can be to do it only when needed.  It might make sense to drop all characters before the first `'<'`.